# What does svc mean in the file winsvc.h?

Tags: c++, windows, header-files

I wanted to know what does svc mean or is its full form, that is present in the name of the header file winsvc.h.

Comment: It means *service*.

Comment: Did you open it? "*Abstract: Header file for the Service Control Manager*"

Comment: @KenWhite I thought the same thing, thank you for confirming.